# python decorator TypeError missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to write a decorator to repeat an erroring function N times with increasingly sleeping times in between. This is my attempt so far:

```
def exponential_backoff(seconds=10, attempts=10):
    def our_decorator(func):
        def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for s in range(0, seconds*attempts, attempts):
                sleep(s)
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        return function_wrapper
    return our_decorator

@exponential_backoff
def test():    
    for a in range(100):
        if a - random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            print('success count: {}'.format(a))
            pass
        else:
            print('error count {}'.format(a))
            'a' + 1

test()
```

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: our_decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using:

```
@exponential_backoff()
def test():
    ...
```

The overall decorator is not designed to have arguments be optional, so you must provide `()` when using it.

If want an example of how to make decorator allow argument list be optional, see:

- https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html#decorators-with-optional-arguments

You might also consider using the wrapt package to make your decorators easier and more robust.

Comment: I see. Brilliant!

Comment: Right, I had the same problem having written `@click.command` instead of `@click.command()` XD

Answer (score 19):

Understand what decorator is:

```
@exponential_backoff
def test():
    pass
```

equals to:

```
def test():
    pass

test = exponential_backoff(test)
```

In this case, `test` is `def our_decorator(func):`. That's why you get `TypeError` when calling `test()`.

---

So further:

```
@exponential_backoff()
def test():
    pass
```

equals to:

```
def test():
    pass

test = exponential_backoff()(test)
```

In this case, now `test` is what you need.

---

Further, `functools.wraps` helps you to copy all properties of original function to decorated function. Such as function's name or docstring:

```
from functools import wraps

def exponential_backoff(func):
#   @wraps(func)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
    return function_wrapper

@exponential_backoff
def test():
    pass

print(test)  # <function exponential_backoff.<locals>.function_wrapper at 0x7fcc343a4268>
# uncomment `@wraps(func)` line:
print(test)  # <function test at 0x7fcc343a4400>
```

Answer (score 5):

Either you go for the solution provided by @Graham Dumpleton or you can just modify your decorator like so:

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def exponential_backoff(func=None, seconds=10, attempts=10):
    if func is None:
        return partial(exponential_backoff, seconds=seconds, attempts=attempts)

    @wraps(func)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for s in range(0, seconds*attempts, attempts):
            sleep(s)
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return function_wrapper

@exponential_backoff
def test():    
    for a in range(100):
        if a - random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            print('success count: {}'.format(a))
            pass
        else:
            print('error count {}'.format(a))
            'a' + 1

test()
```

---

**EDIT**
My answer **was** not entirely correct, please see @GrahamDumpleton's answer which shows how to make my attempt of a solution viable (i.e. [this link](https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html#decorators-with-optional-arguments)). Fixed it now, thank you @GrahamDumpleton !

Comment: I think you will find this will not allow you to supply the ``seconds`` and ``attempts`` argument using decorator syntax. You need a special trick as shown in doc I linked in my answer.

Comment: That is true @GrahamDumpleton! Please accept that my solution is inferior to yours… I am still learning! Additional resource to back @GrahamDumpleton's solution: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#decorator-functions-with-decorator-arguments