# Understanding nested decorators missing required positional argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I wrote two decorators, `verbose` controls whether or not the defined function prints it's output, `announcer` will announce when the function is called.

```
import os
import sys

def verbose(func):
    '''Sets verbose mode on function'''
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(verbboo=True, *args, **kwargs):
        # disabling print
        if not verbboo:
            sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        # running func
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # enabling print again
        if not verbboo:
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        return ret
    return wrapper_func

def announcer(func, endboo=True):
    '''anounces when function is called and when it finishes; if specified'''
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print('run {}.{}@{:%Y%m%d%H%M}'.format(
            func.__module__, func.__name__,
            dt.datetime.now())
        )
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if endboo:
            print('end {}.{}@{:%Y%m%d%H%M}'.format(
                func.__module__, func.__name__,
                dt.datetime.now())
            )
        return ret
    return wrapper_func
```

I then nest the following function with the decorators

```
@verbose
@announcer
def f(boo, opboo=True):
    if boo:
        print('This is True')
    if opboo:
        print('This is also True')

    return f

# testing
f(True)
```

But I receive the following error

```
run __main__.f@202006021152
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mpl/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mpl/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/project/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    f(True)
  File "/home/user/project/decorators.py", line 18, in wrapper_func
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/decorators.py", line 47, in wrapper_func
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'boo'
```

---

The error only occurs when I nest `verbose` on top of `announcer`. `announcer` by itself works fine. What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python decorator TypeError missing 1 required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891951/python-decorator-typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Comment: It doesnt answer why `announcer` works by it's own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

`def wrapper_func(verbboo=True, *args, **kwargs):`

A function definition has to have all of the positional arguments before any of the keyword arguments.  Probably the keyword argument verbboo interfered with the positional argument boo getting passed through.

When I put the verbboo parameter at the end, it still didn't run, but when I put it between *args and **kwargs, it did run.