# First time using decorators, what am I missing?

Tags: python

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
       self.score = 0
       self.wins = 0
       self.losses = 0


    def tally(self, func):
        def wrapper_function(w):
            print("Wins: {}\nLosses: {}\nTotal Score: {}".format(self.wins, self.losses, self.score))
            return func(w)
        return wrapper_function()

    @tally
    def record_win(self, w=1):
        self.wins += w


user1 = User()
user1.record_win()
```

The error that I'm getting is: `TypeError: tally() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

**EDIT** This post is different from the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891951/python-decorator-typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument) because in that post the decorator functions were not instance methods.. which I see now adds some peculiar requirements.

Comment: indentation is the issue there, definitely

Comment: You are missing `self` for the wrapper function.

Comment: add a tab or 4 spaces before all lines after `class User:`  and before `user1 = User()`

Comment: spacing is crucial, here

Comment: @rv.kvetch Sorry didn't know pay attention to how stack overflow represented my text, but it is indented properly in the code and still same error. And I added proper indents to this post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python decorator TypeError missing 1 required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891951/python-decorator-typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Sorry no, while the two posts are similar, I don't see the problem in that post being that the decorator is an instance method which I see now adds a whole new set of problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining `tally` as an instance method, but it's really just a decorator function (it can't be called on an instance in any reasonable way). You can still define it in the class if you insist (it's just useless for instances), you just need to make it accept a single argument (the function to wrap), without `self`, and make the *wrapper* accept `self` (while passing along any provided arguments to the wrapped function):

```
class User:
    # ... other methods unchanged ...
    def tally(func):
        def wrapper_function(self, *args, **kwargs):  # Accept self + arbitrary arguments to make decorator useable on more functions
            print("Wins: {}\nLosses: {}\nTotal Score: {}".format(self.wins, self.losses, self.score))
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # Pass along self to wrapped function along with arbitrary arguments
        return wrapper_function                 # Don't call the wrapper function; you have to return it so it replaces the decorated function
    
    @tally
    def record_win(self, w=1):
        self.wins += w

    # Optionally, once tally is no longer needed for new methods, but before dedenting out of class definition, do:
    del tally
    # so it won't stick around to appear as a possible method to call on instances
    # It's done all the work it needs to do after all
```

Removing the `w` argument in favor of `*args, **kwargs` means you don't need to specialize to specific function prototypes, nor duplicate the defaults of the function you're wrapping (if they don't pass the argument, the default will get used automatically).

Comment: @rv.kvetch: Actually, that won't work. `@staticmethod` only works once the class has finished being defined (it relies on the descriptor protocol being invoked to remove the `staticmethod` wrapping); if you try to `@staticmethod` and use it *while* the class is being defined, you'll get fun new errors (`TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`).

Comment: yep, i just realized that after trying it out. deleted my earlier comment xD